# WAMP server: Cannot get localhost to work

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, skype

When i click on the local host tab of my WAMP server it opens up the webpage but gives a blank page with the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

I have researched online about the problem and uninstalled Skype and turned off my firewall as suggested. However it did not solve it.

What else can be done to solve the issue?

When I "test port 80" within the apache tab I get the following message:

Your Port 80 is actually used by:

```
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

note: The WAMP server is online, yet the icon is still red. I am using a windows 64 bit laptop.

Comment: Make sure IIS is disabled. Control Panel > Uninstall Programs > Windows Features > Internet Information Services

Comment: Thank you, ISS is already disabled.I think I have cleared port 80 by disabling web deploy. However, now instead of my orignal error I just get "Google chrome could not connect to local host" instead?

Comment: Go to http://127.0.0.1 and tell me if that works

Comment: did http://127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: if you open a command prompt and type `netstat -aon | more` it will tell you what Windows process ID is listening to port 80. Open Task Manager and identify the program by its PID. It will most likely be IIS still or something like Skype. Close Skype and see if Apache begins to listen.

Comment: If you are getting "Google chrome could not connect to local host" then you do not have a web server serving pages running (what Chrome is expecting). It will most probably be Skype. If you need Skype then you will have no other option but change the Apache port to, say, 8080

Comment: Shouldn't need to as of (I think) Vista? the default hosts file shouldn't need to be edited. I run XAMPP and it's basically exactly the same product. I would probably change the Apache config to listen on a different port... just remember to put the port number at the end of your URLs

Answer (score 0):

- Left Click on the `WAMP` icon in the tray.
- `Apache` > `httpd.conf`.
- Search for the `Listen` word and change the 80 that refers to port number `X` and change it with another number (make sure that you have changed all the 80 numbers related).
- Start the Apache server and you will be online listening on port `X` (you need to add `:X` to Apache WWW address to access Apache).